# Doubts in definition of continuity in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, self-learning

**EDITED**

Let $(X, \mathscr T_X)$ and $(Y, \mathscr T_Y)$ be two topological spaces. Let there be a function $f: X \to Y$. Then $f$ is said to be continuous if for every $E \in \mathscr T_Y$ the corresponding $f^{-1}(E)$ is open in $(X, \mathscr T_X)$, i.e. $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathscr T_X$.

**My doubts:**

**1.** Does this mean that continuity of $f$ depends on $\mathscr T_X$, If we change $\mathscr T_X$, $f$ might cease to remain continuous?

**2.** Can we define continuity in the following way: Let $\{E_i \mid i \in I \}$ be a family of **all** open sets in $\mathscr T_Y$. If the set $\{f^{-1}(E_i) \mid i \in I \}$ **is a topology** such that $\{f^{-1}(E_i) \mid i \in I \} = \mathscr T_X$, then $f$ is continuous.

**3** What if $\{f^{-1}(E_i) \mid i \in I \} $ is NOT a topology. Then, given $Y, \mathscr T_Y$ and a given $X$, can $f$ ever become continuous?

If *YES* then how?

**4** Will the definition stated by me in "Doubt 2" be an equivalent definition of continuity?

Please help!!

Comment: 1. Yes, continuity depends completely on topology.
2. $f$ will be continuous **with respect to this particular topology**. Take a look at the notion of [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology)

Comment: If $\{f^{-1}(E_i) \mid i \in I \}$ is NOT a topology then can I make $f$ continuous, keeping $X,Y$ and $\mathscr T_Y$ same. (i.e only changing $\mathscr T_X$)

Comment: What are $E_i$'s? Do you mean the family of __all__ open sets in $\mathscr T_Y$?

Comment: Yes, exactly... (now i have added **all** in my question)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means exactly that. In fact, any function from a space X with the discrete topology is continuous. Similarly, every function to a space $Y$ with the indiscrete topology is continous.

As for the definition of continuity, I think this is the most intuitive definition: $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff for every $x\in X$ and every $V$ neighborhood of $f(x)$ there's a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$.

The set $\{f^{-1}(E_i)|i\in I\}$ is always a topology, because $\{\}=f^{-1}(\{\})$, $X=f^{-1}(Y)$, $\bigcup f^{-1}(E_j)=f^{-1}(\bigcup E_j)$ and $\bigcap f^{-1}(E_j)=f^{-1}(\bigcap E_j)$.

You require $\{f^{-1}(E_i)|i\in I\}=\mathscr T_X$ which is strictly stronger than what the standard definition says which is $\{f^{-1}(E_i)|i\in I\}\subseteq\mathscr T_X$, take the discrete topology on X for an example.

If $f$ is surjective, then $\{f^{-1}(E_i)|i\in I\}\supseteq\mathscr T_X\Longrightarrow(\forall A\in\mathscr T_X)\ f(A)\in\mathscr T_Y$, which is the definition of an open map (image of every open set is open).

If $f$ is bijective, then $\{f^{-1}(E_i)|i\in I\}\supseteq\mathscr T_X\Longleftrightarrow(\forall A\in\mathscr T_X)\ f(A)\in\mathscr T_Y$ and your definition means exactly that $f$ is an open continuous map, which is equivalent to $f$ being a homeomorphism (since $f^{-1}$ is continuous iff $f$ is open for bijective $f$).

Comment: I know this definition. But doubts came when I read the other definition(posted in question). Please resolve my second doubt, especially the 2nd part of my second doubt.

Comment: @Richard J You know the other definition is equivalent to mine, right? (I mean the open set preimage definition)

Comment: yeah. i even proved this definition (posted in question) by assuming the definition given by you. I just want to get an intuitive feel of the definition posted in the above question.

Comment: wow!! I think you just resolved all my doubts. (at least for now; until I think more and some other doubt might come up!)